# pytest unable to discover tests in VSCode

Tags: python, testing, visual-studio-code, installation, pytest

My project structure looks like this:

```
src/
├---__init__.py
└---domain/
    ├---__init__.py
    ├---model/
    |   ├---__init__.py
    |   └---model_mapper.py
    └---util/
        ├---__init__.py
        └---utils.py
test/
├---__init__.py
└---unit/
    ├---__init__.py
    └---test_model_mapper.py
```

And the `settings.json` is:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\asant\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./src"],
    "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "gitlens.currentLine.enabled": false,
    "gitlens.hovers.currentLine.over": "line",
    "gitlens.codeLens.enabled": false,
    "gitlens.hovers.enabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "test"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false
}
```

The line `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./src"],` was necessary, otherwise flake8 complains about every import inside the scripts and I have to prepend `src.` to every one. Besides this, when I try to run the test discovery from the built-in VSCode button I get from the output:

```
=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________ ERROR collecting test/unit/test_model_mapper.py _______________
ImportError while importing test module 'd:\asant\...\test\unit\test_model_mapper.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Users\asant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test\unit\test_model_mapper.py:2: in <module>
    from domain.util.model_mapper import ModelMapper
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'domain'
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR test/unit/test_model_mapper.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
==================== no tests collected, 1 error in 0.10s =====================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\asant\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.926500501\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    main(tool, cmd, subargs, toolargs)
  File "c:\Users\asant\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.926500501\pythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\__main__.py", line 100, in main
    parents, result = run(toolargs, **subargs)
  File "c:\Users\asant\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.926500501\pythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\pytest\_discovery.py", line 44, in discover
    raise Exception("pytest discovery failed (exit code {})".format(ec))
Exception: pytest discovery failed (exit code 2)

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\asant\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.926500501\out\client\extension.js:9:437028)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)]
```

Even adding `src.` to each import inside the `test_model_mapper.py` file won't help.

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo demonstrating the issue, which you can link to from your question? That might make it easier to debug

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the source code, the issue is generated by the files I pointed out in the question I'm sure

Comment: What I mean is, could you make a minimal example GitHub repo that someone could clone and open in VS Code locally to replicate this? It doesn't need to contain the actual source code of your project, it just needs to replicate the issue.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, [this](https://github.com/anphetamina/error-repo.git) is a sample repo that for me fails to discover the tests inside the `test` folder. The python path inside the `.vscode` folder should be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a `.env` file to set the `src` folder in `PYTHONPATH` otherwise pytest is unable to find the `model` package.
Also, putting `conftest.py` inside the `src` folder doesn't help as suggested by someone.